# When I run Windows Update, I get error code 0x80070002

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

When I open windows update, it just says error, with the code 0x80070002
I try to check for new updates and it just stops at downloading 0%, and says error.
I am a new to computers what do i do. Thankyou

Comment: Thank you for your sharing!

Comment: You can copy and paste 'error 0x80070002' into google , or  bing etc. It will lead you to windows update and can be a number of problems but you could get this answer:     Sometimes the error 0x80070002 occurs because the system update process fails, and the Windows Update installation files are corrupted or missing. So you can try to delete the installation files or rename the installation folder to solve the problem. Before we modify the files or folder, you may need to stop the Windows Update service.

Comment: I have been in the business IT world for over 20 years, and have run my own web design business for the last 6 years. I wrote this guide for people who may run into this issue, and the fact that I worked with Microsoft, and they gave me an internal document not available to the public.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with microsoft support, and they said these directions were on their internal documentation. These steps fixed this error for me.

```
Open cmd as administrator

Run these commands, make sure it says service stopped successfully, or not started.

net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver

ren C:\\Windows\\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\\Windows\\System32\\catroot2 Catroot2.old

Run these commands, make sure it says service started successfully.

net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver

Restart, then try windows update again
```

That worked great for me.