# Impossible to update nor add optional functionalities inside Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I've tried everything on my computer (being an Acer Nitro 5 running Windows 11 with an Intel Core i7 9750H / Nvidia GeForce 1660Ti).

SFC /scannow returns nothing, apart of the CBS.log file telling me I'm missing lots of things.

Reinstalling Windows from scratch is possible, but I have lots of things inside it, and losing all my contents + apps wouldn't be the best solution for me to handle.

Updating Windows 11 (via an genuine ISO) tells me this.

0x8007001F - 0x20006
The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during REPLICATE_OC operation

I cannot download updates via Windows Update, it tells me I have this error for each update he finds : 0x80070002

I cannot install optional features, list being blank. DISM fails to restore health around 63.2%, telling that "I have no source files". Also tried external sources (mounted WIM file from my Windows 11 ISO), still says I have no source files, command being DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:C:\data\sources\install.wim:4 (I have Windows Education, hence index 4)

I have 3 partitions : the main one (C:), a Recovery partition, and an ESP one.

I cannot launch MMC from my account, it tells i've basically lost the Administrator rights and I cannot open it (however, other programs do work, but i'm being nagged 24/7 with some random UAC popups when I'm not supposed to).

If you have any ideas, please tell me. Thank you in advance !

Comment: So you are getting this error, when you mount a Windows 11 21H2 ISO, and run setup.exe from within Windows? The fact DISM is unable to repair your system indicates severe system corruption. If you have attempted to provide a source for the DISM command (although you have not specified what the syntax you used so I have no idea if it was correct) indicates a potential problem with the storage device and likely the only forward is a clean install. Can you provide the log from Setup Diag?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Disk Management?  I am looking for something specific about your partitions.  Additionally can you run [these commands](https://superuser.com/questions/1604522/when-i-run-windows-update-i-get-error-code-0x80070002) and then try to install something through Windows Update?

Comment: @Ramhound I had a WIM file, so the syntax was this one : 

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:C:\data\sources\install.wim:4 (I have Windows Education, hence index 4)

SetupDiag just opens and nothing comes out. A blank, 0-octet file.

As for the screenshot of Disk Management, something tells me the corruption got off the ability for me to open the MMC command.

Though I have 3 partitions : the main one (C:), a Recovery partition, and an ESP one.

Comment: Typically would mount the image and then run it against WinSxS. Setup Diag generates a log. Why don't you just provide a screenshot and [edit[ your question instead of providing helpful information in temporary comments?

Comment: Made the necessary changes on OP.